# ng-change does not work with ng-repeat with options but works with ng-options

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-options

I have created select options with ng-repeat, but the function set with on-change is never called.

```
<select>
<option ng-model="level1Selected" ng-repeat="item1 in level1" ng-change="setLevel2()" value="{{item1}}">{{item1}}</option>
```

I recreated the same thing with ng-options, and the function gets called:

```
<select ng-options="item1 for item1 in level1" ng-model="level1Selected" ng-change="setLevel2()"></select>
```

I have checked the documentation, and I see no reason for this difference. The variable level1 is an array of strings, so I don't understand why they behave differently.

The function is currently just a placeholder with console.log:

```
$scope.setLevel2 = function() {
    console.log("value: ");
}
```

Comment: put `ng-change` on the `select` element not `option` since it is `select`'s value that changes

Comment: `ng-change` would work on `select`/`input`, it isn't intended(never) work on `option` tag

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to do that you need to put ng-model and ng-change in select tag, try this:

```
<select ng-model="level1Selected" ng-change="setLevel2()">
    <option ng-repeat="item1 in level1"  value="{{item1}}">{{item1}}</option>
</select>
```

Comment: You are missing the closing tag for the <select>

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I accept this, because it came earlier than Mihai's answer which is basically the same. Can you fix the missing curly brace? And please also change ng-chanche for ng-change too.

Answer (score 1):

You need trigger `ng-change` directive to `select` element.

The `ng-change` event is triggered at every change in the value.

Here is a working solution: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ionutmihai1995/Lvc0u55v/12459/)

```
 <select ng-model="level1Selected"  ng-change="setLevel2()">
    <option  value="{{item1}}">{{item1}}</option>
 </select>
```

JS

```
$scope.setLevel2 = function() {
   alert();
}
```